# Отображение поста wordpress внутри всех рубрик к которым привязан пост

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть рубрики bmw, mers, audi и тд.
Есть пост, в котором описание некой услуги для данных авто.
Задача: выводить в посте текст "для bmw", "для mers", "для audi" и тд. в зависимости от того в какой рубрике находимся.
Если привязать пост к одной рубрике, то задача реализуема. Если к нескольким то при выводе будет "для и_тут_основная_рубрика" кроме того, чпу всегда тоже будет основной рубрики.
Дублировать посты для каждой рубрики не вариант, слишком много выходит и они все одинаковы. Есть плагин для реализации такого функционала?

Comment: В ВП при выводе поста нет такого понятия "в какой рубрике находимся". Тут пост - главная сущность. А рубрика, метки и пр - это, грубо говоря "обвязка".. ну или если угодно "свойства" поста. Поэтому для начала нужно определиться с признаками "в какой рубрике находимся" и от этого уже плясать.

Comment: Хорошо, как тогда определить в какой мы рубрике. Вот есть пост и он назначен всем рубрикам. Как только мы находясь в одной из рубрик переходим в этот пост признак того, что мы именно в этой рубрике какой?

Comment: Что значит "в какой мы рубрике находимся"? Мы не в "рубрике", а получаем документ (пост) по совершенно конкретному урлу. Соответственно для разных документов - разные урлы. Такова в общем случае логика любого правильного сайта вне зависимости от движка. (тут не берётся во внимание финты типа мультиязычности с куками и тп технологии)

Comment: Поэтому чтобы решить задачу, ты уже сам придумай как определять (признаки) "в какой рубрике находимся", а потом уже можно будет что-то решать (шорткодами напр).

Comment: Вот в том и дело, что не могу придумать. Самый очевидный вариант дублировать пост (услугу) и привязывать к каждой рубрике. Но это будут дубли одного и того же поста, делать так ради того что бы в тайтле добавить одно слово и изменить одну картинку чрезмерно избыточно. Вот и ищу решение, как внутри одного поста получать данные о том в какой мы рубрике и исходя из этого метаполями добавлять изменения.

Comment: ну если ты сам не можешь придумать по каким признакам определить "в какой рубрике находимся", то  как же ты придумал задачу.. По волшебству что-ли? Разберись сперва что я про соответствие "документ-урл" писал. Это основа интернета.

Comment: Ты писал про соответствие документ-урл и это понятно, если мы привяжем пост к одной рубрике и в чпу у нас есть вывод рубрик мы и получим тот самый нужный урл. Так здесь вопросов как бы нет. Какой урл мы получим если пост назначен 200 рубрикам, а их будет примерно столько. Естественно всегда один и тот же, так работает вордпрес. А я спрашивал про решение, которое позволит не дублировать пост, а создать его всего один и назначить всем 200 рубрикам, при этом при переходе в данный пост с конкретной рубрики получать пост с признаками именно этой рубрики. Вот такое как сделать?

Comment: "в чпу у нас есть вывод рубрик" - ВОООТ. Это один из возможных признаков. Теперь опять перечитай что ты написал выше и подумай над отсутствием других признаков и на дублями по разным урлам (при разных урлах). Это первое. Второе, более главное - пойми же наконец: нет такого понятия "мы в рубрике", есть "мы запрашиваем документ по урлу". Вникни же в это! (ЗЫ. кроме урла я вижу ещё один возможный "признак" - рефферер. Но это кривой и страшный костыль)

Comment: Этот костыль однозначно не подходит. Какие есть еще идеи?

Comment: Осознай же выше написанное и понимание придёт.